# Len() problems with csvSchema 1.1.0

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, python-3.x

Alright I am using the python open source package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CsvSchema/1.1.0 for csv validation throuhg rules that I set and it seems to have some very obsolete documentation. I am going through each field in the file and check for length and if it is within min length / max length declared within the rules it should pass. Strangely it does not. The code snippet is here :

```
class TestCsvStructure(BaseCsvStructure):

a = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 1000,)#4 bytes
b = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 1, max_length = 3,)
c = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 7,)
d = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 3,
e = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 8,)
f = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 255,)
g = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 255,)
h = StringColumn(blank = True, min_length = 0, max_length = 255,)
```

Now when I pass my file through, column 1 has only 3 characters but it still produces the error :

> feed number = 5
>   [u'Line 5, column 1: The value can not be longer than 3', u'Line 5, column 2: The value can not be longer than 7', u'Line 5, column 3: The value can not be longer than 3', u'Line 5, column 4: The value can not be longer than 8', u'Line 5, column 18: The value can not be longer than 2', u'Line 5, column 19: The value can not be longer than ...

["[u'115133']", "[u'chg']", "[u'Female']", "[u'No']", "[u'Active']", "[u'Primary Name']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'Silvi']", "[u'']", "[u'Ojuland']", "[u'']", "[u'Relative or Close Associate (RCA)']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'Citizenship']", "[u'Estonia']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'']", "[u'115131']", "[u'Daughter']", "[u'No']", "[u'']", "[u'30-Jun-2012']", "[u'']"]

As you can see column 1 = 'chg' with length 3 and should pass but the error says [u'Line 5, column 1: The value can not be longer than 3' . .

Anyone have experience with the package csvSchema 1.1.0 might be able to help.

Comment: Why do you have the value of the column, as a repr'd version of a list with a single item... eg: `"[u'chg']"` (as that is more than 3 chars...) ?

Comment: Exactly - if that line is the real input that the parser is getting, column 1 is not 'chg' with length 3, it's "[u'chg']" with length 7.

Comment: OMG, I feel stupid now. I just spent 2 hours wasting over this. Shit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you pass the arguments in this form: TestCsvStructure([e1, e2,.., en], no_line) ?

Where e's are the elements and no_line = number of current line in CSV file.

Comment: No, as you can see in my code a,b,c... are the arguments (fields/columns ina  csv row) . I define rules for each field and I go row by row in the csv

Comment: Can be more precise when you say "I pass my file through"? How exactly do you pass your file?

Comment: Well, I solved it was just the unicode making the length much bigger. My bad, Thanks anyways!